# Passing parameters to vue-router in iframe of laraval application fails

Tags: laravel, vue.js, iframe, vue-router, quasar-framework

I have a strange error on a project of mine.
I'm trying to switch a laravel project to something where the backend is seperated from the frontend.
Backend api stays laravel, but frontend is vue with quasar.

Since we want to do the change gradualy, i made one new feature in quasar and want to integrate it in my existing laravel-app.
In order to accomplish that, i'm using an iframe in which i load the new vue frontend.
Everything works as it should work, except for one crucial thing.
I have one id-parameter from laravel that should be passed to the iframe (the quasar/vue application), and for some reason... that's not working.

I've tried to work with route parameters

```
<iframe src='/spa/12'
```

and in vue-router

```
 { path: '/:id', component: () => import('pages/weekSchedule.vue') }
```

Without success

I've tried query parameters in the url   like this

```
<iframe src='/spa/index.html?id=12'
```

I can see the correct url in my network inspector, the url is called with the query, but i can't seem to get the parameters in vue.

```
async mounted() {
    this.id=  this.$route.query.id
}
```

When i test it -not in iframe- everything is working.
But in iframe i get nothing.

Does anybody have an idea/solution?
Any help is appreciated!